# C#, returning an array in a function

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a method that generates an array. I want to return this array so I can use it another method. Here is my code so far:

```
public static Array[] generateFirstArray(int seedValue)
{
    int[] firstArray = new int[20];
    Random randomNumber = new Random(seedValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
    {
        firstArray[i] = randomNumber.Next(0, 4);
    }

    return firstArray;
}
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'System.Array[]'

I tried to add [] after firstArray but still not working.

Answer (score 13):

Your return type is currently an array of `Array` objects.  Change your return type to an array of `int`s (`int[]`):

```
public static int[] generateFirstArray(int seedValue)
```

Answer (score 6):

The signature of your methods says you're trying to return an Array of Array (`Array[]`).

You want to return an `int[]` instead so just change your signature to

```
public static int[] generateFirstArray(int seedValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

the return type of your method must be `int[]` and not `Array[]`

Here is one more way of implementing it

```
int Min = 0;
int Max = 4;
Random randNum = new Random(seedValue);
int[] firstArray = Enumerable
                   .Repeat(0, 20)
                   .Select(i => randNum.Next(Min, Max))
                   .ToArray();
return firstArray;
```